# Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Есть ли возможность удалить сообщение из Azure Service Bus Topic по его идентификатору?

Answer (score 0):

Есть. Либо используя `MessageId` или `SequenceNumber`.

Если имеется `SequenceNumber` сообщения, можно запросить сообщение с соответствующим `SequenceNumber` с помощью [`MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(int64)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_ReceiveAsync_System_Int64_). `MessageReceiver` должен будет сконфигурирован принимать сообщения в состоянии [`ReceiveAndDelete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.receivemode?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_ReceiveMode_ReceiveAndDelete).

При отсутствии `SequenceNumber`, сообщения можно просканировать при помощи [`MessageReceiver.PeekBatchAsync()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.peekbatchasync?view=azure-dotnet) и найдя нужное сообщение "удалить" при помощи вышеописанного метода с `SequenceNumber`.